# Samba server do my login credential have to be identical to windows username

Tags: login, samba, configuration, file-sharing

Title says it all but is it like windows username = test123 so samba user has to be test123 too or is there way to change this? so i could be logged in windows with test1 and login to sambe using username test2?

Comment: When you set up the Windows share, you can give other users on the computer permission to access it. That means you can use their users to login instead. If you need to learn how to do this, you need to ask  on [su], as [ubuntu.se] does not deal with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you need to select the function "map network drive" in the explorer. Where this function is accessable depends on your windows version. In Windows 8 it is in the ribbon `Computer` if you select "Ccomputer" in the navigation bar. In this dialog you may activate the option `connect using different credentials`.

Or you open a cmd shell and use the command `net use \\computer\share /user=samba-user`. Windows asks then for the passwort.

Comment: http://imgur.com/lDzNN2X mhmm not working ? :) i created new folder to try it out i tried different letter on the network drive i tried creating new account but no success i only got it work when i had same username as in windows. Because many people use it i cant just go everytime someone uses different device add it to valid users / group

Comment: you can not establish two connection with different credentials at the sam time - so when windows already logged you on with you windows username/password then your already have  a connection - that is was there in the middle of you screenshot windows tries to tell you...